# xcode shows error "magick/magick-config.h" file not found when archiving an app

Tags: xcode

I'm using ImageMagick for my app and it's working perfect on Devices and Simulator but when I tried archiving it,Xcode show me an error "magick/magick-config.h" file not found" in MagickWand.h file.

```
#if !defined(_MAGICKWAND_CONFIG_H)
# define _MAGICKWAND_CONFIG_H
# if !defined(vms) && !defined(macintosh)
#  include "magick/magick-config.h"            <<<<<<<<< This line error
#  else
#  include "magick-config.h" 
# endif
```

Thank you.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem including a different library and "solved" it by removing the part after the slash. i.e. change: `include "magick/magick-config.h"` to: `include "magick.h"`. Might be worth a try.

Comment: Thank you Robert for your trick. It's work! but xcode give me another 56 memory leak and dead store!

Comment: Hmm - not sure about the memory leak, I'm afraid. Maybe something to do with not deallocating? Glad you got the first issue sorted though. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

For using ImageMagick library in Xcode make sure to have these settings (Build tab of the project information):

Other Linker Flags: -lMagickCore -lMagickWand -lz -lbz2 -ljpeg -lpng
Header Search Paths: $(SRCROOT) – make it Recursive
Library Search Paths: $(SRCROOT) – make it Recursive
On the lower left click on the small-wheel and select: Add User-Defined Setting

Key: OTHER_CFLAGS
Value: -Dmacintosh=1
In Link Binary with Libraries under Build Phases,

you may also need to add:
libxml2.dylib

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem including a different library and "solved" it by removing the part after the slash.

i.e. in your case, change:

```
include "magick/magick-config.h"
```

to:

```
include "magick.h".
```